# python module pygoogle installed but no _init_.py file

Tags: python

I installed the `pygoogle` module for Google search on Python.
I downloaded the module package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygoogle) and run the Python `setup.py` install successfully:

```
navyad@ubuntu:~/Downloads/pygoogle-0.6$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygoogle/pygoogle-0.6.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygoogle/pygoogle-0.6.egg-info
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygoogle.pth
```

But while importing the `pygoogle` module, I got an `ImportError`:

```
>>> from pygoogle import pygoogle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygoogle
```

Then, I checked the installation folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygoogle` and saw that there is no `__init__.py` file.

It seems that because of that, it is giving the `ImportError`.

Why is  the `__init__.py` file not created?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the module name is "google".

Try `import google`, as in this example:

http://pygoogle.sourceforge.net/dist/readme.txt